# How to close two Browser instance in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

```
        public void ECM_20245() throws Exception {
        String org = null;
        checkout = new CommonCheckoutModule();
        mini = new MiniCartModule();
        orderAction = new OrderActionsModule();
        ShoppingCartModule cart = new ShoppingCartModule();
        orderHist = new IntelligoStoreOrderHistoryLandingModule();
        order = new OrderHistoryLandingModule();
        org = ConfigurationLibrary.BuyingForData.get("Buy_InvoiceStore");
        OrgSelectorModule select = new OrgSelectorModule();
        String roleA = ConfigurationLibrary.prop.getProperty("ECCROLE_ADMIN_STORE");
        OrderConfirmationModule confirm = new OrderConfirmationModule();
        checkout.buyingForMyself();
        checkout.checkoutSingleIndividualCertificationPrdOrg();
        mini.validateMiniCart().viewCartClick();
        cart.validateShoppingCartPage();
        cart.getGrandTotalPriceFromCart();
        cart.ClickProductFromShoppingCart();
        mini.clearCart();
        select.orgBuyingFor(org);
        checkout.SingleIndividualCertificationoption();
        mini.validateMiniCart().viewCartClick();
        cart.validateShoppingCartPage();
        cart.checkoutSelection();
        confirm.chooseOrgFromConfirmation(org).selectConfirmation();
        checkout.enterPurchaseCodeForStore().selectInvoiceAndSubmit();
        checkout.orderSuccessValidation();
        String orderId = order.getOrderIDFromOrderConfirmationPage();
        orderHist.ctaLinkValOrderActivationPageForIC();


        CommonLibrary.newBrowserLaunch();
        ConfigurationLibrary.loginForAllEnv(roleA, "UserId1");
        orderAction.orderSearchInAdmin(orderId).storeOrderDetailsValForOrg();
        
    }
```

In the above code CommonLibrary.newBrowserLaunch(); launches new browser and executes set of code..Testng aftermethods close the latest opened browser but not existing browser. I cannot use driver.quit since Testng execution will be in parallel .. Can both browser instances be closed? ( one can be closed with @aftermethods)

Answer (score 0):

Set windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

```
// Iterate through the window handles and close each window
for (String windowHandle : windowHandles) {
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
    driver.close();
}
```

You can try above code to close all open windows